# Why isn't my JQUERY code working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm really sorry for askin such a stupid question, but why isn't my code working?? It is driving me nuts already, this is a simple code but for some reason it is not working? Maybe i have missed something and new pair eyes may help me. It is suppose to fadeout everything and then fade in only the element with a class of 'kategooria'. It does fade out everything like it is suppose to do, but nothing fade's in when i click on a li under 'element' div.

console.log displays kategooria in console, so this means that div has that class, but for some reason it won't fade in. I also tried adding fade in command right after fadeout, using some random class, but it wouldn't work either.

JQUERY

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.element ul li').click(function(){
    var kategooria = jQuery(this).html();
    jQuery('.elemendid').fadeOut();
    jQuery('.elemendid > div').each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass(kategooria)){
            console.log(kategooria);
            jQuery(this).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 element">
    <ul><li>moodulmajad</li>
        <li>ELEMENTMAJAD</li>
        <li>FERMID</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="elemendid">
   <div class="moodulmajad">
      <h2>MOODULMAJAD</h2>
         [gallery ids="104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118"]
  </div>
<div class="ELEMENTMAJAD">
    <h2>ELEMENTMAJAD</h2>
        [gallery ids="880,878,884,882,832,829"]
</div>
<div class="FERMID">
   <h2>FERMID</h2>
        [gallery ids="104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118"]
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @aquaman It's a variable

Comment: Because you fade out `.elemendid` and fade in `.elemendid > div`. The parent stays hidden so nothing is visible. You need to do `jQuery(this).parent().fadeIn();`

Comment: I thought if i fade out parent element i can still fade in elements inside parent element, but i guess not. But then how i'm suppose to fade in elements in that parent? i only need to fade in div's with certain class element.

Comment: Just wondering why is everyone downvoting this question? The OP has a problem, he clearly stated it, he posted his code, obviously he tried to solve it before asking. Everything is according to SO rules, but still..

Comment: Then you can do `jQuery('.elemendid > div').fadeOut();` to hide the individual elements instead of the container. You can't have child elements visible if the parent is hidden, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/pajovepire/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @JJJ GUYS/GALS i'm so sorry for being that dumb. It's pretty logical answer to my question...

Comment: Okay, the code worked. Thanks! I'm still sorry asking such a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code**

```
jQuery(function(){
                    jQuery('.element ul li').click(function(){

            var kategooria = jQuery(this).text();



            jQuery('.elemendid > div').each(function(){

                if(jQuery(this).hasClass(kategooria)){
                    console.log(kategooria);
                    jQuery(this).fadeIn();
                }else{
                    jQuery(this).fadeOut();

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

fadeOut() and fadeIn() are async. In your code, you fadeOut() the parent and then fadeIn() a child. This won't work.
Even though the behaviour is weird, the following code should do what you expected :

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.element ul li').click(function(){
    var kategooria = jQuery(this).html();
    jQuery('.elemendid > div.'+kategooria).stop().fadeIn();
    jQuery('.elemendid > div').not('.'+kategooria).stop().fadeOut();
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your HTML and JavaScript to this:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.element ul li').click(function(){
      var kategooria = $(this).text();
      $('.elemendid > div:visible').fadeOut(function() {
        $('.elemendid > div.' + kategooria).fadeIn();
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 element">
    <ul><li>moodulmajad</li>
        <li>ELEMENTMAJAD</li>
        <li>FERMID</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="elemendid">
   <div class="moodulmajad">
      <h2>MOODULMAJAD</h2>
         [gallery ids="104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118"]
  </div>
  <div class="ELEMENTMAJAD">
    <h2>ELEMENTMAJAD</h2>
        [gallery ids="880,878,884,882,832,829"]
  </div>
  <div class="FERMID">
    <h2>FERMID</h2>
        [gallery ids="104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118"]
  </div>
</div>
```